# Get multiple list grouped by different fields

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I'm using this method to send multiple list to client.

```
 public ResponseEntity<?> getFiveLastRequestOfEachVehicleType() {
    ResponseContent content = getResponseContent();
    Map<String, List<Request>> map = new HashMap<>();
    GroupBy groupBy = new GroupBy();
    groupBy.initialDocument("vehicleTypeEnum");
    query = new Query();
    queryFieldsFilterLastFiveRequest(query, VehicleTypeEnum.NEISAN);
    map.put("NEISAN", mongoOperations.find(query, Request.class));
    query = new Query();
    queryFieldsFilterLastFiveRequest(query, VehicleTypeEnum.BADSAN);
    map.put("BADSAN", mongoOperations.find(query, Request.class));
    query = new Query();
    queryFieldsFilterLastFiveRequest(query, VehicleTypeEnum.BUJE);
    map.put("BUJE", mongoOperations.find(query, Request.class));
    content.setData(map);
    return getReturn(content);

}
```

And this method apply criteria to each query

```
private void queryFieldsFilterLastFiveRequest(Query query, VehicleTypeEnum vehicleTypeEnum) {
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("vehicleTypeEnum").is(vehicleTypeEnum));
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("unlock").is(true));
    query.fields()
            .include("id")
            .include("goodsTypeTitle")
            .include("originCityTitle")
            .include("price");
    query.limit(5);
}
```

I wonder if there is any way to retrieve all list in one request to database using MongoOperations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go to grouping manually later on, first query for all vehicleType :

```
private void queryFieldsFilterLastFiveRequest(Query query, VehicleTypeEnum... vehicleTypeEnum..) {
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("vehicleTypeEnum").in(vehicleTypeEnum));
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("unlock").is(true));
    query.fields()
            .include("id")
            .include("goodsTypeTitle")
            .include("originCityTitle")
            .include("price");
    query.limit(5);
}
```

Here the `is` has been changed by `in`, and accept a list of VehicleTypeEnum

Then to use it :

```
 public ResponseEntity<?> getFiveLastRequestOfEachVehicleType() {
    ResponseContent content = getResponseContent();
    Map<String, List<Request>> map;

    query = new Query();
    queryFieldsFilterLastFiveRequest(query, VehicleTypeEnum.NEISAN, VehicleTypeEnum.BADSAN, VehicleTypeEnum.BUJE);

    map = mongoOperations.find(query, Request.class).stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(r -> r.getVehicleTypeEnum().name(),r -> r));
    content.setData(map);
    return getReturn(content);

}
```

Here i use the stream api to group result by VehiculeTypeEnum name